# sleep for many days with resolution of microseconds

Tags: c++, sleep

Is there a way to put a thread to sleep for many days with a resolution of microseconds? usleep can only put the thread to sleep for 1000000 and sleep works in second steps. Is there a way to, may be, use both sleep and usleep to achieve this?

Comment: Note that usleep does not have microsecond granularity: The  usleep()  function suspends execution of the calling process for (at least) usec microseconds.  The sleep
       may be lengthened slightly by any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or by the granularity of system timers.

Comment: The system clock could easily drift by microseconds across days, so even if there were a method available it might not be accurate.

Comment: I really wonder what could require to sleep for days with a microsecond resolution.

Comment: @ereOn me too. That's like worrying about a skyscraper being a micrometer too tall. Maybe the normal case would be like seconds or minutes, not hours or days, but he just wants to allow it to be days robustly.

Comment: @drawnonward: Never mind the clock. The length of a day itself varies by several thousand microseconds. (Sources: JPL/NASA, IERS). This is mainly due to tides.

Answer (score 5):

While it is not yet time to wake up:

- Check the current time
- Go to sleep a bit shorter than when you want to wake up.

This way, you can periodically check the time, increasingly faster and more detailed as you reach the time you want to wake up.

Comment: @lies If you wait for a signal, why do you need a sleep? Use a message queue

Comment: @lies: It usually helps a lot if you post your intended use in the question. There might be better alternatives than *sleeping*, but if you only ask about sleeping then you will not get that information. *'Be careful if you don't know where you are going, because you might not get there'* -- Yogi Berra

Answer (score 5):

Just divide the large sleep in several small sleep periods.

```
int64_t time_to_sleep = ...;
int peroid_to_sleep = ...;
while( time_to_sleep > 0 )
{
     usleep( period_slept );
     time_to_sleep -= period_slept; 
}
```

Comment: ... and add even more drift to the meassure. If you are going to do this, it would be better to `sleep()` for the integer part of seconds and `usleep()` for the remainder time.